# Google IMA-SDK and UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-ima

I am using the Google IMA SDK in the table view. The video ad will display within the video cell as expected. But the scroll won't work in video cell while the ad is playing. Are there any ways to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not feasible to do ios UITavleViewCell as per your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/xoOO4pPyM_M/m/E10sxIZEAQAJ) on the Google Forums from one of the IMA SDK Team:

> The behavior in which the page is not scrollable when pressing the video player while the ad is playing is an intended behavior, and this is something that would be fixed on your own implementation. One workaround is that by adding an event listener on the container element passed to the AdDisplayContainer for “touchmove” events to trigger the scroll on your page.